# how to Configure DHCP time out via program?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, network-programming

On Linux machine i would like to write a program to change the timeout value of DHCP connection (How long the DHCP client can wait before giving up).

i went through the https://askubuntu.com/questions/203157/timeout-in-a-connection-to-a-dhcp-server but this provides the change  of configuration file manually.

Please provide some help

Comment: DHCP never gets a response if it doesn't ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

The DHCP client settings are stored in an ordinary text file, [`dhclient.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhclient.conf). There's a `timeout <time>;` option that you want to add or change.

Comment: Is there any system call which i can call and provide the time out i need ?

Comment: I don't know of one, and I'd be surprised if there were one. Why do you think there would be one?